# To display errors and warnings in the terminal for a React app with Vite

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, vite

I've created a Vite app with React and TypeScript. I've noticed that no warnings or errors appear in the terminal, even when there actually is an error. The error shows up in the browser console, but I'd like to see them directly in the terminal as I was used to with my old app using React and TypeScript (without Vite).

How can I view errors and warnings directly in the terminal after launching my Vite app?
This is the result I'd like to achieve, similar to what happened with my old app.
[image]

Do I need to modify something in the `vite.config` file, or is there a plugin to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [vite-plugin-terminal](https://github.com/patak-dev/vite-plugin-terminal) or [Console Ninja Extension](https://console-ninja.com/). The first option you will need to update your codebase to add terminal logs.